# Take input from csv file and use it to create a custom-made table in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, foreach, csv

I have a csv file that looks like this:
Scott,
William,
Todd,Esben, 
Martin, 
Jesper, 
Alexander W.L

Right now, the names are written this line

```
\aebuildtable{20}{Scott,William,Todd,Esben, Martin, Jesper, Alexander W.L}
```

I want to include a csv file, then the names are written into the table automatically.

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{geometry}
  \geometry{
  a4paper,
  total={210mm,297mm},
  left=5mm,
  right=5mm,
  top=10mm,
  bottom=10mm,
  }

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\def\aeunit{0.25cm}
\newsavebox\tictactoebox
\begin{lrbox}\tictactoebox
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=\aeunit-0.4pt/3,
                      y=\aeunit-0.4pt/3,
                      every node/.style={outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=\aeunit-0.4pt},
                      baseline={($(current bounding box.center)+(0,-\aeunit/2)$)},
                     ]
    \draw    (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
    \foreach \myn in {0,1,...,3}
      {    \draw (0,\myn) -- (3,\myn); }
    \foreach \myn in {0,1,...,3}
      {    \draw (\myn,0) -- (\myn,3); }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{lrbox}

%% draw the extended vertical lines between marked columns
%% #1 column where to draw vertical line                  
\newcommand\aeDrawBorderAt[1]{%%
  \coordinate (B/C#1/top) at (R1/C#1);
  \coordinate (B/C#1/bot) at (R\aeMaxRowCount/C#1|-R\aeMaxRowCount/bot);
  \draw[blue,line width=0.6pt]
    (B/C#1/top)
    ++
    (0,4pt+\baselineskip)
    --
    (B/C#1/bot);
  }

%% label the columns              
%% #1 left column number          
%% #2 right column number         
%% #3 content for labeling columns
\newcommand\aeLabelColumns[3]{%%
  \path (R1/C#1) -- (R1/C#2) node[midway,above,yshift=0pt] {#3};
  \aeDrawBorderAt{#1}
  %\aeDrawBorderAt{#2}
}

%% #1 = number of columns to create
%% #2 = list of names              
\newcommand\aebuildtable[2]{%%
  \foreach \myn [count=\mycnt] in {#2}
  {
    %% previous value 
    \pgfmathsetmacro\myp{int(\mycnt-1)}
    %% set nodes that fix each row
    \ifnum\mycnt=1\relax
      \coordinate (R\mycnt) at (0,\mycnt-1);
    \else                   
      \coordinate (R\mycnt) at (R\myp/bot);
    \fi
    %% a coordinate for the bottom of each row
    \coordinate (R\mycnt/bot)  at ($(R\mycnt)+(0,-3*\aeunit)$);
    %% node for name:
    \node[anchor=north east,outer sep=0pt] (N\mycnt) at ($(R\mycnt)+(-4pt,-\aeunit/2)$) {\myn};

    \draw[blue,line width=0.6pt] ($(R\mycnt)+(0,-\aeunit/2 +3.3)$) -- ($(R\mycnt)+(-80pt,-\aeunit/2 +3.3)$);

    \foreach \mycol in {0,...,#1}
    {
      \coordinate (R\mycnt/C\mycol) at ($(R\mycnt)+({\mycol*(\aeunit*3)},0)$);
      \node[outer sep=0pt,
            inner sep=0pt,
            anchor=north west,]  
           at (R\mycnt/C\mycol.north west) {\usebox\tictactoebox};
    }
    \xdef\aeMaxRowCount{\mycnt}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \aebuildtable{20}{Scott,William,Todd,Esben, Martin, Jesper, Alexander W.L}

  \aeLabelColumns{0}{9}{alm. \o l - 6,75kr}
  \aeLabelColumns{9}{15}{special \o l - 7,75kr}
  \aeLabelColumns{15}{20}{guld \o l - 10kr}

\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Look at `datatool` maybe?

Comment: Reinventing `pgfplotstable`?